# What is the meaning of "I get wild on you"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, lyrics

What is the meaning behind the phrase "I get wild on you, baby"?

I tried to find this kind of phrasal verb "get wild on..." , but I didn't find anything. In my head, this could probably mean either that a person is very passionate about something/someone or that a person gets very angry on other person.

The context is **Lana Del Rey**'s song **Nectar of the Gods**.

> *I get wild on you baby,
>
> I get wild and f__ing crazy like you never knew*

Please, tell me something about it if you know the true meaning.

Comment: It isn't a phrasal verb. It's just being creative. For example, he turns up the music, dances crazily and shouts her name. For example.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous and could mean "I go crazy when I'm with you" or "I go crazy and jump on you".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lyrics interpretation is almost always subjective / Primarily Opinion-Based

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'Lana' is making use of metaphor, comparing a person to a drug, and I take this to mean that by using that drug/person, she feels the effects and **loses her inhibitions**, thus getting wild.

Simply put, 'I get high on you'.